# plugin will not offer update even though a new version is available

Tags: wordpress

I made a plugin, made revisions to it, and commited it again, yet in the admin area under plugins, I do not see under my plugin that an update is available.

So I had, say, version 1.2.0 , and now I made a new version 1.9.0 and I commited it, and on the wordpress site if you click the download button you WILL get the 1.9.0 version, but people that already have version 1.2.0 installed won't see an update option.

Also, on the wordpress site, it always says "Download version 1.0", even though the current version is 1.9.5 (that's what it says in the readme.txt under the stable tag)

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your trunk/stable tag setup is off. This is the way [WordPress recommends releasing plugin updates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Updating_Your_Plugin) on their site, and what I use for publishing new version of my plugins.

1. Make changes to your plugin and commit to `/trunk`
2. When you are ready to release a new version update your main plugin PHP file under `/trunk` with the new version number in the [plugin header](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Standard_Plugin_Information).
3. Update [`/trunk/readme.txt`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Readme_File) to include the new changelog info and set the stable tag to the same version as in #2
4. Create a tag of `/trunk` using the same version number specified in the stable tag

The new version of your plugin should not be automatically delivered to anyone who has your plugin installed.

Comment: I did not change the version number in the plugin header, that's the part I missed! Seems to be working now, thanks.